# Group Parent Vertex and Children through Edges into master/sub json array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3, graph-traversal

First of i am using azure cosmos db.

A person `works_for` multiple Offices. Each Office can be `IsMaster` or not. If it is a `IsMaster` it can have `master_of` edge to another Office. Each `works_for` edge has `AccessLevel` property for a person.

Logic: Given a Person name, get all Offices that person `works_for` that are `IsMaster` = 'true'. Then return all `IsMaster` with `AccessLevel` taken from `works_for` and corresponding SubOffices that each `IsMaster` has through `master_of` edge and corresponding `AccessLevel` through `works_for`

My end goal is to produce a JSON object below given a person name:

```
[
  {
    "Master": {
      "Name": "Seattle",
      "AccessLevel": "Admin"
    },
    "Subs": [
      {
        "Name": "Portland",
        "AccessLevel": "NonAdmin"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Vancouver",
        "AccessLevel": "Admin"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Master": {
      "Name": "New York",
      "AccessLevel": "NonAdmin"
    },
    "Subs": [
      {
        "Name": "Boston",
        "AccessLevel": "NonAdmin"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Orlando",
        "AccessLevel": "Admin"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[image]

```
g.addV('Office').property('Name','Seattle').property('IsMaster','true').as('ow1')
.addV('Office').property('Name','Portland').property('IsMaster','false').as('ow2')
.addV('Office').property('Name','Vancouver').property('IsMaster','false').as('ow3')
.addV('Office').property('Name','New York').property('IsMaster','true').as('oe1')
.addV('Office').property('Name','Boston').property('IsMaster','false').as('oe2')
.addV('Office').property('Name','Orlando').property('IsMaster','false').as('oe3')
.addV('Person').property('Name','Zodiak').as('p')
.select('p').addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','Admin').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name', 'Seattle'))
.select('p').addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','NonAdmin').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name', 'Portland'))
.select('p').addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','Admin').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name', 'Vancouver'))
.select('p').addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','NonAdmin').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name', 'New York'))
.select('p').addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','NonAdmin').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name', 'Boston'))
.select('p').addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','Admin').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name', 'Orlando'))
.select('ow1').addE('master_of').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name','Portland'))
.select('ow1').addE('master_of').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name','Vancouver'))
.select('oe1').addE('master_of').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name','Boston'))
.select('oe1').addE('master_of').to(g.V().hasLabel('Office').has('Name','Orlando'))
```

**Update**: I had one of my edges missing a `'AccessLevel'` property that .by() was referencing. Without that property query was failing. Using `coalesce()` I set it to a `"foobar"` value before anything else:

```
outE("works_for").as("e").coalesce(values('AccessLevel'), property('AccessLevel','foo')).select('e').
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your query (the one, that creates the graph) really work in CosmosDB? If others want to follow along, here's the query that creates the graph without nested `g.V()`'s:

```
g.addV('Office').property('Name','Seattle').property('IsMaster','true').as('ow1').
  addV('Office').property('Name','Portland').property('IsMaster','false').as('ow2').
  addV('Office').property('Name','Vancouver').property('IsMaster','false').as('ow3').
  addV('Office').property('Name','New York').property('IsMaster','true').as('oe1').
  addV('Office').property('Name','Boston').property('IsMaster','false').as('oe2').
  addV('Office').property('Name','Orlando').property('IsMaster','false').as('oe3').
  addV('Person').property('Name','Zodiak').as('p').
  addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','Admin').to('ow1').select('p').
  addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','NonAdmin').to('ow2').select('p').
  addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','Admin').to('ow3').select('p').
  addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','NonAdmin').to('oe1').select('p').
  addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','NonAdmin').to('oe2').select('p').
  addE('works_for').property('AccessLevel','Admin').to('oe3').select('ow1').
  addE('master_of').to('ow2').select('ow1').
  addE('master_of').to('ow3').select('oe1').
  addE('master_of').to('oe2').select('oe1').
  addE('master_of').to('oe3')
```

And the query to produce the desired result:

```
g.V().has("Person","Name","Zodiak").as("p").
  outE("works_for").as("e").
  inV().has("IsMaster","true").
  project("Master","Subs").
    by(project("Name","AccessLevel").
         by("Name").
         by(select("e").by("AccessLevel"))).
    by(out("master_of").as("o").
       inE("works_for").where(outV().as("p")).
       project("Name","AccessLevel").
         by(select("o").by("Name")).
         by("AccessLevel").fold())
```

Comment: how would you go about doing it, if for some reason AccessLevel doesn't exist, not empty, but not present at all. Can it be substituted with a blank ' ' value?

Comment: Sure, check out the `coalesce` step: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#coalesce-step